# Ubuntu Server 14.04 does not recognize the hard drive on PowerEdge 2950 with SAS6 iR

Tags: server, system-installation, dell

I have a power edge 2950 with SAS6 iR without PERC and one single hard disk, the SAS controller is active on BIOS and **I'm experiencing issues while installing Ubuntu server 14.04.**

During installation, I see the following prompt:

```
One or more drives containing MDADM containers (Intel/DDF RAID) have been found, 
Do you wish to activate these RAID Devices
```

I choose `YES`.

---

Next I see the following prompt:

```
One or more drives containing Serial ATA RAID configurations have been found 
do you wish to activate these RAID Devices?
```

I choose `YES`.

---

Next I see the following prompt:

```
This is an overview of your currently configured partitions and mount points. 
Select a partition to modify its settings.
```

Then there are three options to choose namely:

```
Configure iSCSI volumes
Undo changes to partitions
Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
```

- choosing `Configure iSCI volumes` asking for a target and I dont have it.
- choosing `Undo changes to partitions` makes crash the installation
- choosing `Finish partitioning and write changes to disk` shows

  ```
  No root file system is defined
  ```

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to press [Ctrl+E] during POST and configure your VDs again in the FakeRAID firmware, then choose the desired boot VD.

After this, restarting the Ubuntu installation process should offer you the fake RAID volumes.

However, you won't be able to complete the installation successfully because of [bug #1370368](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1370368) which prevents GRUB from installing. Even if you skip bootloader installation and install GRUB afterwards (from a desktop LiveCD, for example), the system won't boot from the fake RAID because of an infinite loop during array assembly when Ubuntu boots up:

```
incrementally starting raid arrays
mdadm: Create user root not found 
mdadm: create group disk not found
```

Comment: How to install MDAM https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=408461